# Returning all records from derived table name that also have IN statements

Tags: mysql, derived-table

I'm trying to retrieve a single record from my database, BUT I don't know which table name to query until I query another record.

If I knew the table name and ID the end query would look something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM `materials_sheet_stock` WHERE `id` = 2
```

But since I do NOT know the table name or the ID in that table I'm trying to break it up a bit.

This query will successfully retrieve the table name for the above query

```
SELECT tb1.* 
FROM (SELECT `tag_table` 
    FROM `materials_group_tags_mapping` 
    WHERE `tag_id` IN 
        (SELECT `materials_group_tags`.`id` 
         FROM `materials_group_tags` 
         WHERE `materials_group_tags`.`name` = "frameless_base_side_material_unexposed")) AS tb1
```

which in this case is `materials_sheet_stock`

This query will successfully retrieve the `ID` that I need for the above query

```
(SELECT `materials_group_tags_mapping`.`tag_value` 
FROM `materials_group_tags_mapping` 
WHERE `materials_group_tags_mapping`.`tag_id` IN 
    (SELECT `materials_group_tags`.`id` 
    FROM `materials_group_tags` 
    WHERE `materials_group_tags`.`name` = "frameless_base_side_material_unexposed"))
```

But now when I put them all together in 1 query using IN it keeps throwing errors about not finding columns, or that all tables need an alias.  I've tried editing the following code for like an hour with no luck. Hopefully you guys can spot the error. Here's the final code that I am using.

```
SELECT tb2.* 
FROM (SELECT `tag_table` 
    FROM `materials_group_tags_mapping` 
    WHERE `tag_id` IN 
        (SELECT `materials_group_tags`.`id` 
        FROM `materials_group_tags` 
        WHERE `materials_group_tags`.`name` = "frameless_base_side_material_unexposed") ) as tb2 
        WHERE tb2.`id` IN 
            (SELECT `materials_group_tags_mapping`.`tag_value` 
            FROM `materials_group_tags_mapping` 
            WHERE `materials_group_tags_mapping`.`tag_id` IN 
                (SELECT `materials_group_tags`.`id` 
                FROM `materials_group_tags` 
                WHERE `materials_group_tags`.`name` = "frameless_base_side_material_unexposed"))
```

Comment: "I've tried editing the following code for like an hour with no luck. Hopefully you guys can spot the error. Here's the final code that I am using. " Nice start to learn to also indent and format SQL queries.. SQL query one liners are hard to read, understand, debug and maintain..

Comment: You aren't going to map table names easily in SQL directly unless you construct the query then execute it. This would require using a stored procedure/function. It would probably be easier to do in your calling language (like PHP).

Comment: And to add to @SloanThrasher 's comment besides IN statements arn't the most efficient way to execute this query most likely this query is better written to use JOIN's and executes faster with correct indexing.

Comment: Ok thanks guys.  What is going to be faster to execute.. 2 queries, or 1 query using joins and "IN".  I was writing it this way so I didn't have to run 2 queries.  I will if I have to, but my intentions were to gain speed.